Where to caulk exterior door with leaking window seal
I have an exterior back door with a window that leaks around the trim during hard rains.  The door is likely due for replacing but I'm hoping to buy some time with silicone caulk to better seal the window. I'm not sure if the best approach is the remove the interior trim and caulk around the window seal, or to caulk all the exterior grills.


You always seal from the direction the water comes from, so unless you toss buckets of water on the inside surface, you seal the outside.  Remove all old caulk/sealer, clean and re-seal.

If you remove all the screws from the interior trim, the entire window can be removed from the outside.  However, this can be tricky. There often is caulking holding in some places while other spots come loose easily.  The window can be heavy as well.  This is a 2 person job.
You could just opt to caulk around the window frame on the outside. (both inner and outer flanges), with an acrylic latex caulk. (easy to clean off the glass.)  This may get you some time, if the door will be replaced soon. (Say within a couple of months.)
If you decide to caulk the entire frame, be ready to ply and scrape and cut old caulk off. Then re caulk with a polyurethane caulk. It stretches better and is paintable unlike silicone.
Seal the outside well. No caulking is needed inside.  Be careful to not over tighten the screws when re-installing. The old plastic has a tendency to break.
